# Three JS - BoundingBox not being updated after performing rotations

Tags: javascript, rotation, three.js, bounding-box

I need to find out the bounding box of a geometry after applying rotations on it.

Code to rotate - taken from sample editor of **Three JS**

```
object.rotation.x = xRadians;
object.rotation.y = yRdians;
object.rotation.z = zRadians
```

This rotates the object just fine.

Now I need to get the updated bounding box

Code to get the bounding Box

```
var minX = parseFloat(object.boundingBox.min.x);
var minY = parseFloat(object.boundingBox.min.y);
var minZ = parseFloat(object.boundingBox.min.z);
```

I keep getting the same values in minX-Z no matter what the rotation is. What is the right way of getting the updated bounding box?

I am using r-66.

I also tried using:

```
var radians = x * Math.PI / 180;
var axisX = new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0);
var matrix = new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationAxis(axisX, radians);
geometry.applyMatrix(matrix);
```

This method performs the relative rotation and also updates the bounding box correctly but I  do not want relative rotation. The first approach is what I am looking for but that does not update the bounding box of the object.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Box3.setFromObject( object )` computes the world-axis-aligned bounding box of an object (including its children), accounting for both the object's, and childrens', world transforms.

```
var box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject( object );
```

three.js r.66

Comment: I am not sure if returns the "same" boundingBox as the object.boundingBox does when I use:
var matrix = new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationAxis(axisX, radians);

It seems to be returning entirely different values.

Comment: I am not looking for someone to help me debug the code but I've attached the image to show that the 
var box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject( object );
does not seems to be giving right values:

[link](http://s8.postimg.org/7al6q5dit/3_JSRotation.png)

Also why does plain object.boundingBox not work?
Thanks!!

Comment: You mean `geometry.boundingBox`. `Geometry.boundingBox` does not take the transform into consideration. Look at the source code so you understand what it is doing.

Comment: Can you pl point me to what part of code should I look to see where transformation is performed?

Comment: You appear to have fundamental misunderstandings. You can compute the bounding box of a rotated mesh, or you can compute the bounding box of a geometry. Alternatively, you can apply a matrix to a geometry, which permanently moves the vertices.

Comment: I agree, being a beginner I must be making some basic mistake here. What I want to do is to get updated boundingBox after I've applied the rotation to THREE.Mesh.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Well, I answered that question. Please remember to "accept" this answer by clicking on the check mark. Then, if you are having additional problems, make a new post, show your code, and ask a specific question about it. You'll get there!

Comment: Well, the following code does not return 'right' bounds:

`var box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject( mesh );`

But I'll mark the answer anyways.

Comment: setFromObject is bugged. I seem to periodically run into issues where the bounding box keeps growing if it has (stationary) children added to it (just once).

Comment: @NickWiggill Would you be willing to file a bug report? See "How to report a bug" in the [guidelines](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md).

Answer (score 3):

```
var box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject( object );
```

will return the world coordinates, so you need to subtract them from it:

```
var bbox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(object);
bbox.min.sub(object.position);
bbox.max.sub(object.position);
```

This will give you the correct bounding box relative to the object.